# Customizing facebook share button in Django?

Tags: python, django, facebook

I am trying to customize the content of my facebook share, but I haven't been able to do this successfully. As per the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/webmasters). I have added the og tags:

```
        <meta property="og:url" content="www.mysite.com" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Check out this link" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="This is a test description" /> 
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://img1.123freevectors.com/wp-content/uploads/new/icon/075-smiley-face-vector-art-free-download-l.png" />
```

My facebook html contains this:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button"></div>
```

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

When I debug this code using the facebook debug tool, I get warnings. These warnings don't make sense to me since when I inspect element the og tags are in the head section. The warnings are:

```
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: As per which "docs"?

Comment: I used this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/webmasters